# how can i set the Text Message by default when i start the SMS activity from my App?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

i launch the **Default SMS Activity** from my Android app in order to send an SMS , using the following Code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
startActivity(intent);
```

but i want to Set some text directly in my `EditText` which contain the text message ( when i launch the Default SMS Activity , the `EditText` is empty )  . how can i do this  ?

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its really simple. Just add `sms_body` data to the intent

```
String messageBody = "This sms message"
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
intent.putExtra( "sms_body", messageBody );
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:
*`Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));

                smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "share text");

                startActivity(smsIntent);`*